# Heroku: Long running Rake task eventually crashes

Tags: heroku, rake

I have a rake task I'm going to use only once, to import a massive CSV file.

```
heroku run:detached bundle exec rake owners:import
```

The rake task works ok locally.  It runs for > 8  hours on Heroku, but eventually crashes.   The task is not completed.  Checking processes:

```
heroku ps  
=== web (Standard-1X): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: up 2018/01/09 22:52:22 +0000 (~ 10h ago)

=== worker (Standard-1X): bundle exec rake jobs:work (1)
worker.1: crashed 2018/01/10 09:19:05 +0000 (~ 28m ago)
```

The log does not give any information at all

```
> heroku logs --app mydemoapp --dyno run.8945
>
```

I have a 1x standard worker process, which I thought this would use automatically.  Is that wrong? Do I set it to use the worker process myself somewhere?

Comment: When you say "crashes" what does that mean? Just returns without any messages and doesn't complete the task?

Comment: @lurker - updated the question to answer that.  I checked through console, not enough records added, looking at heroku ps, it shows it crashed.

Comment: actually, surely that shows that the worker was being used.  so, how to tell what else made it crash without log entries?

Comment: Have you tried running it with the `--trace` option and capturing the output of `rake` in a file? E.g., `bundle exec rake --trace jobs:work > rake.out 2>&1 &`

Comment: If you run with `--trace`, `rake` should give you a big call trace when it aborts. It's a very helpful option when debugging `rake` tasks. Whether you run it in the background as I showed is up to you. I often do it that way then watch the output with `tail -f rake.out` but it allows me to break looking at the output to do something else in the same window if I wish. Or you could just run it in the foreground and walk away and check hours later. :)

Comment: Hi @Will, i have exactly the same problem, did you find out why it crashes ? And how you resolve it please ?

Comment: @Gregdebrick - I think there was a limit of 24 hours per task.  I had to break up the task to run in less time than that to squeeze the data up onto the server.